# Matrix row and column swapping/printing c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to reprint a 2 dimensional array, array[7][3]. I am trying to get it from outputting initially

```
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  6  8
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20 21
```

to then output the selected column first in the matrix but by row, like if you picked column 2, it would output this

```
*3  6  9
12 15 18
21* 1  4 
 7 10 13
16 19  2
 5  8 11
14 17 20
```

I am using for loops but I cannot figure out how to do the swapping part. I separately declared them as three different array[7]. I think I properly set the single arrays values to be the same, but the printing is confusing me

This is a snipt of my code that I know isn't working properly

```
//assign to single dimensional arrays

for (index = 0; index < 7; index ++)
{
pickUp[index] = trickDeck[index][columnNumber];
}

for (index = 0; index < 7; index ++)
{
pickUp2[index] = trickDeck[index][first];
}

for (index = 0; index < 7; index ++)
{
pickUp2[index] = trickDeck[index][second];
}



//reassign back to multidimensional

for (index = 0; index < 7; index ++)
{
for (column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
{
trickDeck[index][column] = pickUp[row];
row++;

}
index++;
}

row = 0 ;
for (index = 0; index < 7; index ++)
{
for (column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
{
trickDeck[index][column] = pickUp2[row];
row++;

}
}
row = 0;
for (index = 0; index < 7; index ++)
{
for (column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
{
trickDeck[index][column] = pickUp3[row];
row++;

}

}
}
```

Comment: in the example, where is the 9 coming from ? Is this a typo and it should be 8? Or a 9 in the original?

Comment: you say you only want to print in different order. Does that mean that actually no rearranging of the elments is needed and you only need to print them in different order?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? It's difficult to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about calculating indices.

And integer and modulo division will be you friend. Let us start with calculating the row and the column for a running index 0,1,2,3,4,.....

Of course the dimensions of the 2d array must be known. Let's call them `NumberOfRows` and `NumberOfColumns`

Then, we can simply calculate the row and the column from the running index with:

```
size_t row = runningIndex / NumberOfColumns;   // This is a integer division
size_t column = runningIndex % NumberOfColumns;
```

Ok, that's easy. Now we look at the other way around. We have a row and a column and then want to calculate a running index. Also simple. See:

```
size_t runningIndex = row * NumberOfColumns + column;
```

Next, we want to iterate over special indices / rows / columns. I we look carefully then we can see that we either keep the row and iterate over the columns or keep the column and iterate over the rows.

And again, if we want to iterate over several columns starting with a startColumn as in your case, we can use modulo division. Example:

```
size_t startColumn = 2;
for (size_t columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < NumberOfColumns; ++columnIndex) {
    size_t column = (columnIndex + startColumn) % NumberOfColumns;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < NumberOfRows
; ++row) 
        std::cout << array[row][column];
}
```

This will print an array column by column starting with the start column.

Sometimes you may want to skip some indices. The "skip" is called "stride" and some libraries like boost even to have a stride iterator. In C++ we could use a `std::valarray` in such cases. It satisfies perfectly your needs, but is hard to understand for beginners.

So, but with all what we learned above, we can simply fulfill the task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 7u;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 3u;

using MyArray = std::array<std::array<int, NumberOfColumns>, NumberOfRows>;

int main() {
    // Define array with start values
    MyArray myArray{{
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9},
        {10,11,12},
        {13,14,15},
        {16,17,18},
        {19,20,21}
    }};
    
    // We will store the result in this new array
    MyArray result{};
    
    // We want to read column values starting with column 2
    const size_t startColumn{2u};
    
    // This is the running index of the resulting array
    size_t runningResultIndex{};
    
    // Now iterate over all columns 
    for (size_t columnIndex{}; columnIndex < NumberOfColumns; ++columnIndex) {
        
        // Calculate effective column
        const size_t column = (columnIndex + startColumn) % NumberOfColumns;
        
        // Iterate over all rows
        for (size_t row{}; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        
            // Copy values
            result[runningResultIndex/NumberOfColumns][runningResultIndex%NumberOfColumns] = myArray[row][column];
            ++runningResultIndex;
        }
    }
    // Output
    for (const auto &row : result) {
        for (const int value : row) std::cout << value << '\t';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```